# Redshift Permissions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, privileges

I had a user who has create permissions within Redshift delete a table and create it again. That user no longer has access to even do a Select on the table. Any idea why? I have already done the following command and it hasn't seemed to work:

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schemaname> grant all on schema <schemaname> to <user>;`

Comment: Have you tried something like `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA ... TO youruser;`

Comment: Grant Usage did seem to work but why did my user lose privileges to that table just after deleting it and then re-creating it? @JimJones

Comment: Could it be that this user had access **only** to this table? Otherwise I also cannot explain it. Would you mind if I answer this question with my first comment for proper rating and so that other users can find it better?

Answer (score 1):

The select permission for the tables in the schema is not the permission that is defined for the schema itself. Schema privileges are `usage` (see what's in there), `alter` (rename) and `drop` (remove). To grant select from all tables in the schema by default, you have to use

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA <schemaname> grant all on tables to <user>;
```

see [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DEFAULT_PRIVILEGES.html)

Answer (score 0):

`GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA <schemaname> TO <user>`

**EDIT** @bonsaioak

I cannot see what has happened in this database, but the user somewhat didn't have permission to use (therefore `USAGE`) the schema. I can only speculate that somewhere there was a sort of `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES` to this specific user, but to draw a better conclusion on the source of the problem, one would need to investigate the log files. The `GRANT USAGE` seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: Can you add some context explaining what this command is doing and why it will solve the problem?  If you don't have time to do that just leave the code snippet as comment on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following steps to reproduce the issue and fix it based on the suggestion by AlexYes

1. Create Schemas:

   ```
   create schema schema1;
   create table schema1.table1 (a int);
   create schema schema2;
   create or replace view schema2.view1 as select * from schema1.table1;
   ```
2. Create User:

   ```
   create user testuser with password 'TESTPASSWORD123testpassword';
   ```
3. Create Group:

   ```
   create group testgroup with user testuser;
   ```
4. Grant Usage on Schemas:

   ```
   grant usage on schema schema1 to group testgroup;
   grant usage on schema schema2 to group testgroup;
   ```
5. Grant on existing views in the schema2:

   ```
   grant select on all tables in schema schema2 to group testgroup;
   ```
6. Altering default privileges to the group so that any new object will inherit the grants going forward:

   ```
   alter default privileges in schema schema2 grant select on tables to group testgroup;
   ```
7. Drop and recreate the view:

   ```
   drop view schema2.view1;
   create or replace view schema2.view1 as select * from schema1.table1;
   ```

It works now when you login as testuser and try accessing schema2.view1 (won't work without step 6)!

8. Cleanup after the test is complete:

   ```
   drop schema schema1 cascade;
   drop schema schema2 cascade;
   drop user testuser; 
   drop group testgroup;
   ```

The same should work for Delete as I have it for Select in the example.